# calculation in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

have an access database with a form that has multiple textboxes for production data. I need to do a calculation with a few of the boxes, they are set up as

---

txtA * txtB * txtC = txtD

I need to take the values from each of the boxes and perform this calculation behind the scenes. So I need the value from txtA * txtB * txtC and display the answer to that calculation in txtD. I keep running into issues because of the number of textboxes on my form it will always pick up the wrong data?? HeLP!

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim txt As TextBox

    For Each ctrl In Form.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            Set txt = ctrl
            If txt.Name = "txtD" Then
                Set txt = ctrl
                ctrl.SetFocus
                ctrl.Text = calculate
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub

Public Function calculate()
    Dim calc1 As Double        
    calc1 = txtA.Value * txtB.Value * txtC.Value / 144
End Function
```

I keep getting this error:

> Run-time error '2185':
>   You can't reference a property or mathod for a control unless the control has the focus.

This is in regards to txtA, txtB, txtC.

Comment: You should show your existing code: difficult to know where you're going wrong otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
txtD = calculate()
```

Or

```
Me!txtD = calculate()
```

If, for some reason, you want to access a control by its name, do it like this

```
Dim name As String

name = "txtD"
Me(name) = calculate()
```

Your calculation function must assign the result to the function name. A potential problem is that you are ignoring types. Of which type is the result of the function? It will be typed as `Variant` if you don't specify a type (and a variant can contain about anything). Better

```
Public Function calculate() As Double
    calculate = CDbl(txtA.Value) * CDbl(txtB.Value) * CDbl(txtC.Value) / 144
End Function
```

Now, everyone who looks at the function knows what kind of data the textboxes should contain and, more important, what kind of result the function returns.

Comment: any idea how to get my textbox to display a decimal number? It should be 1.4936 and it keeps showing up 1

Comment: Change the `Format` property of the textbox. You have several choices: General Number, Currency, Standard etc. or you can enter a format like "#.####" or "0.0000".

Answer (score 0):

First off, the line

```
  ctrl.Text = calculate
```

should be

```
  ctrl.Text = calculateBoardFeet()
```

Next, the code

```
  calc1 = txtA.Value * txtB.Value * txtC.Value / 144
```

should be

```
  calculateBoardFeet = txtA.Value * txtB.Value * txtC.Value / 144
```

Comment: Right, sorry I changed the names to simplfy it and forgot to change the boardfeet calculation. it's fixed now. That isn't the problem. :)